# How do I tell robot-server to reset the test fixture when I use ride with Plone?

Tags: plone, robotframework

I'm trying to write my first robot test; I'd like to use ride as advertized in http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.robotframework/happy.html#install-robot-tools

I added

```
initialization =
    import os
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + '${buildout:directory}/bin'
```

to my `[robot]` section to make it possible to run the tests clicking "Start" in ride.

It works, but the second time I run the tests I still see the content created by the first test run.

How do I tell robot-server to go back to a just-initialized state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily (and you should throw me into pool for not documenting this yet in *plone.app.robotframework*'s documentation – I thought that RIDE is too difficult to get running until it works on wxPython 2.9).

In RIDE

1. select **Run**-tab
2. change **Execution Profile** to **custom script**
3. click **browse** to select for **bin/robot** from your buildout as the *Script to run tests*

Click **Start**.

Technically **bin/robot** is a shortcut for **bin/pybot --listener plone.app.robotframework.RobotListener** (I keep repeating **bin/**, because it's important that *plone.app.robotframework* is available in sys.path). Robot Framework Listener -interface is specified in [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.7.7#using-listener-interface).

Our listener calls **bin/robot-server** (using XML-RPC) before every test to testSetUp-methods for the current test layer and after every test testTearDown-methods. This resets the fixture and isolates functional tests.

Comment: Thanks! IIUIC your suggestion makes my [robot] snippet unnecessary. Is it true?

Comment: @silviot, **initialization**-part? If **bin/ride** works also without it, it's unnecessary. On some level, with **bin/robot**, RIDE would work also when installed outside buildout, but running it from the buildout would give it correct paths to locate the all available keywords libraries and show their documentation.